# Replace byte array occurrence that contains `0x00` to the `0x30`

Tags: java, android, byte, arrays, android-bluetooth

I am trying to replace byte array occurrence that contains `0x00` to the `0x30`.

1) ***If byte array is in `string` form. (Do-able)***

```
 String bytes = "0x7d 0x44 0x14 0x05 0x0e 0x01 0x11 0x04 0x2b 0x0c 0x00 0x45";

 if(bytes.contains("0x00"))
    bytes = bytes.replace("0x00", "0x30");
```

2) ***If byte array is in `byte` form. (Problematic)***

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { (byte) 0x7d,  (byte) 0x44,  
               (byte)0x2d,  (byte)0x05,  (byte) 0x0e,  (byte)0x01,  
               (byte)0x11,  (byte)0x10,  (byte)0x2f,  (byte) 0x03,  
               (byte)0x00,  (byte)0x48};

try 
{
    String myString = new String(bytes, "US-ASCII").trim();

    if(myString.contains("0x00"))
    {
        myString = myString.replace("0x00", "0x30");
        bytes = myString.getBytes();
    }
} 
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above method requires to first convert bytes into string form and then replace all the occurences of `0x00` with `0x30` and then convert the resultant string back to bytes.
This seems something not upto the mark. However, despite of that the solution didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether I undestand your question, but this should fix your second listing:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { (byte) 0x7d,  (byte) 0x44,  
               (byte)0x2d,  (byte)0x05,  (byte) 0x0e,  (byte)0x01,  
               (byte)0x11,  (byte)0x10,  (byte)0x2f,  (byte) 0x03,  
               (byte)0x00,  (byte)0x48};


for (int i=0; i<bytes.length; i++) {
    Byte b = bytes[i];
    if (b == 0x00) bytes[i] = 0x30;
}

try 
{
    String myString = new String(bytes, "US-ASCII").trim();
} 
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```